# Red X on all folders

Tags: java, eclipse

So I have used Eclipse for a couple years now, and recently switched to Netbeans. I switched back to Eclipse, so I can work on some SQL projects, but when I opened Eclipse, a whole bunch of red x's appeared. I have never come across this before and don't know how to get rid of it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clean your projects, then check your JVM settings.**

Open the "Project" menu and choose "Clean..." and then select "Clean all projects" and click "OK".

If this doesn't work, then check the project settings.  Make sure it is configured to use a JVM which is actually installed on your system.  My guess, since I can see standard JVM classes highlighted, is that you had chosen to globally use a specific JVM which is no longer installed on your system.

Comment: @user2779767: If you have "`JAVA_HOME`" setting, verify its value.