# red block X's exist on route path says endpoint does not define a valid uri ??? but it does

Tags: jboss-developer-studio

a result of this I believe is causing my endpoint to not move or rename the file on consuming it.  I can't find anything wrong except that somehow Jboss Dev Stdio has red blocks with X and says the endpoint does not define a valid uri, but it does???

nothing I found works, clear project, jboss doesn't allow me to clear project it is greyed out.

![jboss]file:///C:/Users/212555427/Pictures/Saved%20Pictures/Capture1.PNG

get rid of the red blocked X's and reestablish the route.

similar to this link but only on a single path or directory
![jbds][Red X on all folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068216/red-x-on-all-folders)

Comment: Could you please specify what version of Red Hat Developer Studio you use and add affected Camel Context XML file?

Comment: thanks Tomas,  Red Hat Developer Studio
Version: 12.0.0.GA
Build id: GA-v20180710-1916-B2972
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_181

Comment: Tomas, I was able to clear the red blocks by opening the Camel Context's and saving them.  ? do not understand what happened but it is ok now.  thanks so much

Comment: Camel Editor is adding unique id values to all elements which do not have them (they are needed for debugging purposes). Since you didn't send the content of your Camel context XML file, it is hard to tell where was the problem. But I'm happy that it is working after save anyway ;-).